# JMeter : Using multiple CSV files

Tags: csv, jmeter

The following is the scenario I want to run in JMeter: I have one CSV file (file1.csv) containing 100 userIds and passwords. I have created a Thread Group containing 100 users. I want each user to read one row of userId and password from file1.csv. For this I have added a CSV File Config element. Now, I want each of these users to read dynamic CSV file (for first row  of userId and password from file1.csv it should read file2.csv, for
second row  of userId and password from file1.csv it should read file3.csv, for third row  of userId and password from file1.csv it should read file4.csv and so on ) containing some rows. Each row contains parameters for a HTTP request.

Can anyone tell me how to do this in JMeter?

I am generating the one csv file(file1.csv) containing user name and password and other csv files(file2.csv,file3.csv,file4.csv and so on) containing some records.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be adding a [Counter test element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) or [__counter() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) to generate incrementing postfix for secondary CSV files on each iteration and using [__CSVRead() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) for extracting data from your `file1.csv`, `file2.csv`, etc.

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series to learn more about using functions in JMeter tests